# Ruby on Rails bundles downgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on ROR and incidentally I upgraded my bundles with `bundle update` command, I got message that bundles are up to date, but when am trying to start my rails server `rails s` it is throwing me an error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models.rb:88:in `const_get': uninitialized constant Devise::Models::TokenAuthenticatable (NameError)
```

Please tell me what I have to do to solve this. I have done lots of R&D on this, but not get any answer. I installed rails with `sudo apt-get install rails` not RVM. I think there is an option to downgrade rails version with RVM.
please help.

Comment: As you have mentioned you are not using rvm then how you can down grade ? . To install a particular rails version you need to do something like gem install rails -v '3.2.16'

Comment: Thanks Sabyasachi, but am new in rails, and rails was working fine before update the bundles when I run the command to update the bundle its update my all the bundles and now when I start the rails server it throws me an error as I mentioned. Please tell me how can I downgrade my bundles with previous ones.

Comment: Just remove the Gemfile.lock and run bundle install and let me know if its working or not.

Comment: still am getting same error.. :-(

Comment: Sabyasachi, I did what you said but it was not working, than I added devise version in GEM file and install bundles, and then remove secret key from devise and start rails. Now its working. Thanks for your answer and help.

Comment: great (y).. but how it was working previously ?

Comment: actually I think that I was using lower version on devise and its working fine but when I update the bundles than it throws me an error. but happy now that its working fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2739):

`TokenAuthenticatable` has been removed from Devise. So if you are using it in your application, you'll need to remove it.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 -         :recoverable, :rememberable, :token_authenticatable
```

`:token_authenticatable`  should be removed.

Refer this [link](https://github.com/DBNess/codemontage/commit/ce852808d59e89c5bbfd96cad113deef981dfd72) also.

If it works locally it likely means an old gem is being loaded - make sure your gems do not include an old version of devise and in your Gemfile please specify `gem 'devise'` only without the version specifically.

Then, for downgrading ruby version, you need to install RVM in your machine,

Please refer the below links to install RVM and different versions of ruby using it. Then, you can use appropriate ruby versions for different projects. No need to downgrade the system installed ruby version. Also, you can use system ruby version if you need. (`rvm use system`)

http://rvm.io/rvm/install

https://rvm.io/rubies/installing

http://rvm.io/rvm/basics

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Shiv Aggarwal: Answer updated. does it work for you?

Comment: Rajesh its good suggestion I knew this but I want that project become correct as it is. I am using lots of other gems. With RVM I think I have to change every where.. My project is on final stage so I recommend if it become correct as it is..

Comment: @ShivAggarwal: Hey, its not a big deal to install lower versions of ruby using RVM. After all you want to donwgrade, right? Just install RVM and intall the ruby version (to which you want to downgrade) and from the project folder, just run 'rvm use 1.8.7' and run bundle install. Check this link http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rvm/. It will take only 5 minutes to do it. If any issues, use the system ruby version itself by running 'rvm use system'. If it helps you properly, accept the answer.